# Load and save Weka Model using Java API?

Tags: java, weka, text-classification

I have my model on my hard drive at d:\MultiNomial.model.
That model can be run correctly from weka.
The model was built to classify a text using StringToVector as a filter. 
I am using java to load that model using Weka API.
This is my source code

```
import weka.core.*;
import weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayesMultinomial;
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource;
public class Classifier {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        NaiveBayesMultinomial    NBM =(NaiveBayesMultinomial) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read("D:/MultiNomial.model");
        DataSource source= new DataSource(   "D:/test.arff");
        Instances Testset=source.getDataSet() ;
        Testset.setClassIndex(Testset.numAttributes()-1);

        Instance newInstance=Testset.instance(0);
        double PredictVal=NBM.classifyInstance(newInstance);
        System.out.println(PredictVal);

    }

}
```

but I had the following error when I tried to run it from Eclipse:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier cannot be cast to weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayesMultinomial
```

what is the issue?

In Weka I used FilteredClassifier -> Unsupervised-> Attribute->StringToVector.
Then I chose   NaiveBayesMultinomial and I saved my model in my drive.
Now When I used Java, I got the error : weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier cannot be cast to weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayesMultinomial.

I think there must be a way to tell the code how to reverse StringToVector then use :

```
NaiveBayesMultinomial  NBM =(NaiveBayesMultinomial) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read("D:/MultiNomial.model")
```

Comment: As the exception states, the serialized classifier is not of the type you're trying to cast it.

Comment: I am sure they are the same model classifier algorithm. I also created another model J48 and casted to J48 and have the same error !!

weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier cannot be cast to weka.classifiers.trees.J48

Comment: Is the problem because I use FilteredClassifier "StringToVector" and the code does not support how can be done in reverse mode, before applying the Classifier algorithm ?

Comment: @qqilihq updated the question

Answer (score 1):

try to

```
NaiveBayesMultinomial NBM = new NaiveBayesMultinomial();
NBM = (NaiveBayesMultinomial)weka.core.SerializationHelper.read("D:/MultiNomial.model");
```